# Mule:How to combine a list of json values into one

Tags: arrays, json, mule, dataweave

Input JSON

```
{
     "digital-profiles": [{
             "Id": "INTID1",
             "status": "ACTIVE",
             "cId": "12"
         },
         {
             "dId": "INTID2",
             "status": "barred",
             "cId": "13"
         },
         {
             "Id": "INTID3",
             "status": "ACTIVE",
             "cId": "14"
         }
     ]
 }
```

Output:

```
{
     "Results": {
             "NewId": "INTID1:ACTIVE,INTID2:barred,INTID3:ACTIVE"
         }
 }
```

I am trying to achieve the above mentioned output JSON using the input which is mentioned above. How to achieve this using dataweave transformation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [map](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators#map) and [joinBy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators#join-by) to get desired output. This works for me

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
Results : {
    NewId : payload.digital-profiles map ($.Id ++ ':' ++ $.status) joinBy ','
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

this is one way you could do it ( code not tested but working on something very similar at the moment)

```
function ParseJSON(MyObject)
{
// parse incoming var into a JSON object.
var MyObjectParsed= JSON.parse(MyObject);
var i = 0;
var NewJSONstring = "{/"Results/": {/"NewId/":";

// for each profile 
for(;MyObjectParsed.digital-profiles[i];)
{
    NewJSONstring = NewJSONstring+ MyObjectParsed.digital-profiles[i].Id;
    NewJSONstring = NewJSONstring+ ':';
    NewJSONstring = NewJSONstring+ MyObjectParsed.digital-profiles[i].status;
    NewJSONstring = NewJSONstring+ ',';
    i++
}

return  NewJSONstring;
```